# Account merge request for a friend

Tags: support, status-completed

I just convinced my co-author Samuel Russell to proper-register on this site. Unfortunately, his cookie-auth has expired or is on a formatted computer.

Can we merge:

- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/3064/samuel-russell
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/3579/samuel-russell

They all should have the same-email address. (He reports that he thinks he made 3 posts cookie-authed from that address, but a trivial search isn't pulling them up.)

Comment: Done. Done. Done. (Fifteen Characters worth of Done)